# Freeradius Queries, datetime greater than now()

Tags: mysql, datetime, radius, freeradius

I am trying to check if a datetime field is greater (later) than the current date. I keep getting Access-Rejected. I use MySQL as Database.

Here is the full code, the same goes for authorize_reply_query

```
authorize_check_query = "SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op \
  FROM ${authcheck_table} \
  WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}' \
  AND expireon > NOW() \
  ORDER BY id"
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit: In phpmyadmin, the SQL code (with correct tablenames) works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add the new column to the radreply table.

Now it works